# Assigning categories based on percentage within a group in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
CampaignId    Category    Strike
    1            A          2
    1            B          3
    1          Others       5
    2            A          4
    2            B          2
    3            C          1
    3            C          4
    4            A          1
    4            B          1
    4            C          1
    4            D          1
    4          Others       1
```

Then, I would calculate percentage of `Strike` for each `Category` by `CampaignId` like this:

```
SELECT CampaignId, Category, Strike, (SUM(Strike::FLOAT) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId) / SUM(Strike::FLOAT) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId, Category) * 100) AS PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId
FROM myTable
```

resulting in the intermediate table below:

```
CampaignId    Category    Strike    PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId
    1            A          2        20.0
    1            B          3        30.0
    1          Others       5        50.0
    2            A          4        66.6
    2            B          2        33.3
    3            C          1        20.0
    3            C          4        80.0
    4            A          1        20.0
    4            B          1        20.0
    4            C          1        20.0
    4            D          1        20.0
    4         Others        1        20.0
```

Now, I would like to assign a final label, say `FinalCategory` based on the `PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId` calculated above. The gist of the criteria for `FinalCategory` is: if one of the categories in each `CampaignId` is 'Others' `AND` is `PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId >= 30.0`, then the rest of the rows in that `CampaignId` group will be labeled 'Others'. Else, we copy `Category` directly into `FinalCategory`.  The result table should look like this:

```
CampaignId    Category    Strike    PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId    FinalCategory
    1            A          2        20.0                                        Others 
    1            B          3        30.0                                        Others
    1          Others       5        50.0                                        Others
    2            A          4        66.6                                        A
    2            B          2        33.3                                        B
    3            C          1        20.0                                        C
    3            C          4        80.0                                        C
    4            A          1        20.0                                        A
    4            B          1        20.0                                        B
    4            C          1        20.0                                        C
    4            D          1        20.0                                        D
    4         Others        1        20.0                                        Others
```

How could I achieve such thing using as simple SQL query as possible? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CampaignId, Category, Strike, PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId,
CASE WHEN Others_count > 0 AND 
     MAX(CASE WHEN Category='Others' THEN PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId END) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId) >= 30 THEN 'Others'
ELSE Category END AS FinalCategory
FROM (
SELECT CampaignId, Category, Strike, 
(SUM(Strike::FLOAT) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId) 
 / SUM(Strike::FLOAT) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId, Category) * 100) AS PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId
,SUM(CASE WHEN Category='Others' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId) as Others_count
FROM myTable
) T
```

Added to the existing query are

- Others_Count for each campaignId with a `sum` window function
- Use a `case` expression with calculated Others_Count and `max` window function to check if the row with `Others` category has percentage >= 30 and assign 'Others' as final category else use the category as-is.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm. From this, I learned a trick: using the `SUM` of `CASE WHEN` counter as a flag. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your query as a CTE or subquery:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT CampaignId, Category, Strike, 
             (SUM(Strike::FLOAT) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId) / SUM(Strike::FLOAT) OVER (PARTITION BY CampaignId, Category) * 100) AS PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId
      FROM myTable
     )
select t.*,
       (case when OthersFlag = 1 then 'Others' else category end) as FinalCategory
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when category = 'Others' and PercentageOfStrikesByCategoryByCampaignId > 30.0 then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by campaignid) as OthersFlag
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a working a very readable (easy to understand) solution! I accepted vkp's solution as answer because he posted a bit earlier than you did and his answer works for Vertica (not just T-SQL). :)

Comment: @user1330974 . . . This is not a T-SQL answer, although it could easily be modified for it.  What is the issue with this answer and Vertica?

Comment: [`WITH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (or CTE) isn't part of Vertica. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1330974 . . . You can throw it into a subquery instead.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. :) Thank you for the suggestion.